# Blender: how to import externally changed scripts again (reload)

Tags: python, blender

In Blender V2.81a with Python there is a main script that work fine. The main script says

`import f1, f2, ...`

which does also work. Those scripts f1,f2,... are edited in an extern editor (in this case Notepad++). After saving they should reload when running the main script in Blender again. However (due to the way Blender works?) the 'old version' of the scripts are still active and a new (i.e. after editing) define is 'unknown'. In other words: the scripts doesn't seem to reload at all.

How do I import f1,f2,... in such a way that their new content is passed to Blender?

(this question is answered partially elsewhere but either those solutions are not working in Blender V2.81a or the solution works only in the special case mentioned in those answers; is there a generic way to reload all scripts, always and in all cases? I also couldn't find a Python statement to reset the whole Blender session, which could be an alternative option?)

Comment: reload(f1) will reload a module.

Comment: reload(f1) give "NameError: name 'reload' is not defined"

Comment: for 3.x:

from importlib import reload

reload(module_name)

Comment: for V2.81a `import importlib` is ok but your statement raises NameError

Comment: aha, you should split them: `from importlib import reload` and after that: `reload(f1)`